# Scroll background by dragging fingers vertically

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch

I want to change that code instead of scrolling the background itself, to scroll by dragging fingers vertically.

```
private float speed = 0.5f;
Vector2 startPos;

void Start () {

    startPos = transform.position;

}

void Update () {

    transform.Translate((new Vector2(0, -1)) * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (transform.position.y < -19)
    {

        transform.position = startPos;

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

### Use `Input.touchCount`, `Input.GetTouch` and `touch.deltaPosition` to detect how far the touch has moved.

You can ignore `deltaTime` because it's already expressed in how much of the screen has been dragged since the last frame.

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 ) 
    { 
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        float yMove = touch.deltaPosition.y / Screen.height;

        transform.Translate(Vector2.up * yMove * speed);

        if (transform.position.y < -19)
        {
            transform.position = startPos;
        }
    }

}
```